# make an object move across the screen iphone?

Tags: iphone, xcode, animation, uiimageview

I want to simply have a loop so that an object continuously moves across the screen at the bottom. Here is my code it should be pretty easy to understand.

```
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController




    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        [self performSelector:@selector(spawnRocket) withObject:self afterDelay:2]; //delay before the object moves

    }

    -(void)spawnRocket{
        UIImageView *rocket=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-25, 528, 25, 40)]; //places imageview right off screen to the bottom left
        rocket.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:5 animations:^(){rocket.frame=CGRectMake(345, 528, 25, 40);} completion:^(BOOL finished){if (finished)[self spawnRocket];}]; //this should hopefully make it so the object loops when it gets at the end of the screen


    }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @end
```

After doing all this i click run and all i see is a white screen on my iphone 6.0 simulator

ps. im running xcode 4.5.1

Comment: also, i had 2 accounts already a couple months ago and they got banned because i was asking bad questions. I'm not sure if you are allowed to have multiple accounts on stackoverflow, so if you are not allowed and I get banned here I will not make anymore accounts. Although I realize how important this site is and I will not make any unneccesary questions.

Comment: Might be worth providing how `ViewController` is presented/created, it could be an issue there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

1. `UIImageView *rocket=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:...`

   You're not assigning an image to the image view, the best way to do this is to use:

   ```
   UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
   UIImageView *rocket = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
   rocket.frame = CGRectMake(-25, 528, 25, 40);
   ```
2. (The root cause of your problem) You are not adding your `UIImageView` to your main view, hence it's not being displayed. In `spawnRocket`, you should do:

   ```
   [self.view addSubview:rocket];
   ```

   **Note:** Because you want this to be done in a loop, you're gonna have to make sure your memory management is in order.

   I don't know whether you still want the rocket on screen after it's finished moving, but if not, remember to keep a reference to the `UIImageView` and `removeFromSuperview` when you're done (to prevent memory leaks).
3. Calling `spawnRocket` in `viewDidLoad` is probably not the best idea, it may not reach the screen yet when `spawnRocket` is called. Try calling it in `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` (whatever is best in your case)
4. `[self performSelector:@selector(spawnRocket) withObject:self afterDelay:2];`

   You don't need to provide `self` within `withObject:`, you're not accepting any parameters within `spawnRocket`

Answer (score 0):

You don't add the `UIImageView` to any parent view. It will just live in memory, but not be displayed. Add it to your view controller's view after creating it:

```
[self.view addSubview:rocket];
```

Comment: yes but i thought setting the background color would be enough to see it

Comment: Are you running it on a pre iPhone 5 device? Otherwise your y coordinate is too high.

Comment: Also, generally *use NSLog*. See if your methods not working are actually executed.